# flutter website 404 error when i try to reach a page via url

Tags: flutter

i released my flutter website everything is fine navigation is fine.But when i try to reach a
page by url in my browser i get 404.

1- Assume example.com is my website.

2- when i type example.com in url segment , it perfectly opens my website and navigations are fine.

3- but when i type example.com/second in url segment of my browser i get 404 error.

i try to define base href in index.html

```
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
  <base href="/urunlerimiz/">
  <base href="/hakkimizda/">
  <base href="/iletisim/">
  <base href="/magaza/">
```

but it didnt work

please help